# How to insert this date/time value into a datetime field

Tags: mysql, database, date, datetime

I have a date/time values already exist. I want to enter these values into a DB. I might need to do comparison between the fields, for example, which one has expired date. The values are already saved in this format:

```
Jul 20 13:19:10 2016 GMT
```

How can I insert them into a DB? If I used string, I can not compare which is older, etc. that's why I need to insert them as Date/Time.

But the question is how?

EDIT:
I am loading from text file. So It is not an available field. I just need to know how to define it and insert it.

Comment: You probably need a staging area.  Load the data in to a table that matches the defintion of the text file, so this particular column would likely just be a `VARCHAR(24)`.  Then you can use internal functions to coerce it to a different data type when doing something like `INSERT INTO targetTable SELECT blah, STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(stringDateColumn, 'GMT', '') , '%b %d %H:%m:%i %Y') FROM stagingTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the MySQL function [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Jul 20 13:19:10 2016 GMT', '%M %d %T %Y')
-- Gives '2016-07-20 13:19:10'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function  STR_TO_DATE to convert the string

STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE('YOUR_VALUE', 'GMT', '') , '%b %d %H:%m:%i %Y')

I stripped the GMT part